# Angular 8 Passing element ref to method

Tags: typescript, angular8

I would like to know if i could pass an element to a method like this in angular 8

```
<div #linkExplained>
...
</div>

 <div (mouseleave)="somefunction(linkExplained)" >
</div>
```

this works when running on dev. When i try to build a production build it says
Property 'linkExplained' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in a different way

```
<div id='id1' #linkExplained>
...
</div>

<div id='id2' #linkExplained>
...
</div>

 <div (mouseleave)="somefunction('linkExplained')" >
</div>
```

in the component file

```
  @ViewChildren("linkExplained") linkExplainedList: QueryList<any>;
```

then looping over like so

```
 somefunction(elementId: string) {
   this.linkExplainedList.forEach((item: ElementRef) => {
      if (item.nativeElement.id == elementId) {
        //do something
      }
    ));
}
```

kind of roundabout way but gets the job.

If anyone does know if the answer to the question I posted about would be appreciated